# Как определить источник атаки?

Tags: безопасность, взлом, аудит

Была попытка атаки путем подмены данных платежного поручения из 1С в банк-клиент. Единственное, что удалось найти это "HEUR:Trojan.Script.Generic", который увидели Касперский и Eset в HTML-файлах с сайта glavbukh.ru. Очень похоже на правду.
Оригиналы обоих HTML доступны по линкам:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iey0wqp73gkadu8/158401-perenos-vycheta-po-nds-s-2014-na-2016-god%5B1%5D.htm?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfe41dw2zv8rhqc/197499-qqqm1y17-ip-i-fizicheskoe-litso-imushchestvo%5B1%5D.htm?dl=0

Есть идеи где именно здесь "собака зарыта"?

Comment: Предлагаете всем желающим подгружать себе трояны?

Comment: @VTT, очень надеюсь, что это у вас такой тонкий юмор))

Answer (score 3):

Трояны в HTML не живут, и никакого кода трояна в html быть не может. Даже не буду смотреть на код, скажу, что инфицирован говнокод, скорее всего хакеры нашли хранимую XSS, или может быть просто фишинг, и уже с помощью известной техники, атаковали цель. Сложно сказать, что там у вас произошло, так как я вслепую ответ пишу, можно сказать, black-box. Тем более, откуда я знаю, может у вас там RCE есть, чем хакеры и пользуются (и будут пользоваться до тех пор, пока вы не пофиксите этот вулн). В общем, вариантов - туева хуча)

Теперь касательно идей, где "собака зарыта"

- Идея номер 1: Хранимая XSS
- Идея номер 2:  Фишинг
- Идея номер 3: RCE
- Идея номер 4: Тупоголовые бухгалтера

Как пофиксить:

1. не жалеть средств на аудит (только не аудит а-ля фриланс от скрипт-кидди Васи, а присоединиться к какой-нибудь программе)
2. фиксить все вулны по классификации OWASP-10.
3. к компьютеру допускать только тех людей, кто хоть немножко знаком с таким понятием, как ИБ.

Заключение: [RCE](http://insafety.org/rce.php)